# How to resolve NetBios names on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, networking, samba, hostname, netbios

I know there's `smbutil lookup` command, but I would like to know how to get it in the system lookup, similar to what is possible on Linux by modifying `/etc/nsswitch.conf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using avahi/mDNS/bonjour and just added .local

Comment: Could you perhaps explain in more detail? I wanted something really simple and just clicks away to make everything work, if it's possible. Adding ".local" simply doesn't work.

Comment: All the windows computers on my network have iTunes installed, and the linux computers have avahi-daemon. They both support mDNS with little or no setup, allowing host resolution with the Mac (as well as iPhone, etc.) via mDNS. The mDNS name is typically just the hostname.local I rang Apple support and this was the best they could get for me, I don't think Mac OS X 10.7 in general supports NetBios name resolution (or at least not without a WINS server), only some applications like Finder do for finding computers on the network.

Comment: Thanks!! You should have edited your answer with this awesome info, rather than commenting! This really did help me. :)